# Pandas dataframe comparison script takes days to run, is there a more efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, large-files

I am fairly new to python, I've made a script which works well on my test data (3 CSV files with a few thousand entries) but on my actual data (3.99GB CSV, 1.5GB CSV and third smaller CSV) it's been running for about 24 hours without completion.

The script compares single cell RNA sequencing (scRNAseq) data of a chicken in a pandas dataframe (1.5GB) to a ortholog reference (also pandas df) and converts the chicken data row names to their ortholog, or if no ortholog is available drops the row. Then the fish scRNAseq CSV (3.99GB) is converted to dataframe and is compared to the ortholog-converted chicken dataframe. If the fish row name is not found in the chicken row name, then the fish row is dropped. Conversely, if the chicken row name is not found in the fish row names, it too is dropped and new CSVs for both fish and chicken are created.

Associated column information needs to be preserved, as does order of rows, hence why I'm including the column information (>30,000 columns).

Is this something that I could try making more efficient or should I just try this on a faster computer?

Data looks like this for the chicken and fish files, gene and cell IDs are unique. There's about 50,000 columns x 30,000 rows in the chick data and ~75,000 columns x ~45,000 rows for the fish data:

| NaN | cell1 | cell2 | cell3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GeneA | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| GeneB | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| GeneC | 0 | 0 | 1 |

For the ortholog file, I have this:

| Gene | Chicken (Maternal Broiler) | Homology type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| geneA1 | GENEA | one2one |
| geneB4 | GENEB | one2one |
| geneC2 | GENEC | one2one |

And finally my code:

```
    import pandas as pd


#creating a dataframe
## plan:
# 1)take chick csv and convert all genes to orthos, drop those that aren't Orthos -- done
# 2) take fish csv, convert to df and drop all those that don't exist in the new chick df form step 1


## this take the converted chick df and compares it to the unaltered fish df
## it then finds genes which are in both datasets and keeps them,
## and then drops those which do not match
def fish_only_orthos(fish, chick, ortho):
    chick_data = orthologue_conversion(chick, ortho)
    fish_data = fish_dataframe(fish)
    cond = ~fish_data['Gene'].isin(chick_data['Gene'])
    fish_data.drop(fish_data[cond].index, axis = 0, inplace = True)
    cond1 = ~chick_data['Gene'].isin(fish_data['Gene'])
    chick_data.drop(chick_data[cond1].index, axis = 0, inplace = True)
    fish_data.rename(columns = {'Gene':""}, inplace = True)
    chick_data.rename(columns = {'Gene':""}, inplace = True)
    print(fish_data)
    print(chick_data)
    fish_data.to_csv(f"fish_homologous_final.csv", header = True, index = False)
    chick_data.to_csv(f"chick_homologous_final.csv", header = True, index = False)


## creates dataframe from fish scv file
def fish_dataframe(file_name):
    file = pd.read_csv(file_name, header = None,  dtype=str)
    col_names = list(file.T[0])
    col_names[0] = 'Gene'
    file.columns = col_names
    #print('zfish df', file)
    return file

#creates dataframes for the orthologs & chick data, appropriately renames columns
def get_dataframe(file_name, type):

    if type == 'ortho':
        file = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = "\t")
        file.rename(columns = {"Gene name":"Zebrafish", "Chicken (maternal Broiler) gene name":"Chicken", "Chicken (maternal Broiler) homology type":"Homology"}, inplace = True)
    elif type == 'data':
        file = pd.read_csv(file_name, header = None,  dtype=str)
        file.rename(columns = {0:"Gene"}, inplace = True)
    else:
        print(f'Unknown "Type" for file: {file_name}... check code.')
        return
    return file

## parses though chick csv, renaming orthologs and dropping those that aren't renamed
def orthologue_conversion(data_file, orthologue_file):
    orth = get_dataframe(orthologue_file, 'ortho')
    data = get_dataframe(data_file, 'data')
    col_names = list(data.T[0])
    col_names[0] = 'Gene'
    for x in range(len(data)):
        if data["Gene"][x] in orth["Chicken"].unique():
            id = orth.loc[data["Gene"][x] == orth["Chicken"]].index.values
            data["Gene"][x] = orth["Zebrafish"][id[0]]
        else:
            data.drop(x, axis = 0, inplace = True)
    #print(data)
    data2 = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Gene"], keep='first')
    data2.columns = col_names
    #data2.to_csv(f"{data_file[:-4]}1_new.csv", header = False, index = False)
    return data2





## Take fish csv and compare to chick csv and drop all fish rows that aren't fish


def main():
    fish_data_file = "counts.csv"
    chicken_data_file = "GSE159107_E18chick_count.matrix.csv"
    orthologue_file = 'chick_ortho_with_homology_edited_nodup.tsv'
    chick_test_data = 'chick_test_data.csv'
    fish_test_data = 'fish_test_data.csv'

    #ortholog_conversion(chick_test_data, orthologue_file)
    fish_only_orthos(fish_data_file, chicken_data_file, orthologue_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're iterating over the rows (`for x in range(len(data)):`) this is usually the slowest you can achieve in pandas. Revise the logic to use vectorial operations

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense that the for loop would be a huge bottleneck. Any suggestions for how I could change the `orthologue_conversion` function into a vectorial operation? I'd be able to adapt that for all other functions but I don't know how to start

Comment: Can the vectorial operation preserve the row order? @mozway

Comment: maybe, probably, depends on the exact logic. Honestly, I didn't have the courage to go through all the details of your code, do I don't have a workaround to suggest.

Comment: No problem, thank you for the suggestion anyway, code is still running so hopefully it'll just be a one-and-done deal